# Character values stored in DATAFRAME with Double Quotes while reading into R

Tags: r, dataframe, double-quotes, read.table, read.csv

I have a csv file with almost 4 millions records and 30 + columns.
The Columns are of varied type that includes Numeric, Alphanumeric, Date Column, character etc.

**Attempt 1:**
When I first read the file in R using **read.csv Function** then only **2 millions of the records** were read.
This may have happened because of some special characters in the DATA.

**Attempt 2:**
I provided the argument ***quote = ""*** in **read.csv Function** and all the records were read succesfully.
**However this brings up 2 issues:**

a. all teh Columns were appended with 'x.' modifier:
**egs.: x.date , x.name**

b. all the Character Columns were loaded in dataframe, **enclosed with double quotes ""**

Can someone, please advise me that how to resolve these 2 issues and get the data loaded in R succesfully?

*I work for a financial insititution and the data is highly sensitive, hence cannot paste the screenshot over here.
I also tried to create the scenario at my home but all my efforts were of little or of no avail.*

The below screenshot is closest I have came to the exact scenario:
[DATAFRAME SCREENSHOT: Not exact copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QtN0.jpg)

Comment: Did you test the common comma, semicolon, tab, and whitespace delimiters? (easy accesible via, for example, the RStudio 'Environment'?)

Comment: If you provide a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve it is much more likely you get the desired answer from the community. You also may want to try read_csv function from tidyverse http://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html